# while using arbitary keyword argument in a function, all key value pairs are not printed while printing a dictionary

Tags: python, function

```
def build_profile(first, last, **info):
profile ={}
profile["first_name"] = first
profile["last_name"] = last
for key, value in info.items():
    profile[key] = value
    return profile
```

current_profile = build_profile("pawan", "rodriguez", current = "KTM", location = "colombia")
print(current_profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def build_profile(first, last, **info):
    profile ={}
    profile["first_name"] = first
    profile["last_name"] = last

    for key, value in info.items():
        profile[key] = value
    return profile

current_profile = build_profile("pawan", "rodriguez", current="KTM", location="colombia") 
print(current_profile)
```

using return inside for loop only assigns one key word value and exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with indentation and the `return` should be outside of the `for` loop:

```
def build_profile(first, last, **info):
    profile ={}
    profile["first_name"] = first
    profile["last_name"] = last
    for key, value in info.items():
        profile[key] = value
    return profile

current_profile = build_profile("pawan", "rodriguez", current = "KTM", location = "colombia") 
print(current_profile)
```